# Stack trace not available for ANR in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-anr-dialog

I am facing issue while debugging our ANR's. After fixing few ANR's in the last releases suddenly facing the TOP ANR's not having any stack trace.
[image]

Any idea what is the issue over here. My code having Native code also.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.. Come on, Google!

Comment: Any luck with this? I have this exact same problem and on my top two ANR issues.

Comment: Since Google isn't helping properly with ANRs, you can try out a handy tool named ANR-WatchDog https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog

Comment: Thank you for that link, I would be a bit scared of using that on production without some serious testing by I will definitely test it even if just to see which parts of my app are taking longer than I would like. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No update from the Google. But you can use
[github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog) as mention by Sabet in the comment section.
Very handy tool, easy to integrate and use. I used it with firebase crashlytics. It provide better logs/stacktrace then google.

**How it works**

The watchdog is a simple thread that does the following in a loop:

1. Schedules a runnable to be run on the UI thread as soon as possible.
2. Wait for 5 seconds. (5 seconds is the default, but it can be
   configured).
3. See if the runnable has been run. If it has, go back to 1.
4. If the runnable has not been run, which means that the UI thread has
   been blocked for at least 5 seconds, it raises an error with all
   running threads stack traces.

Comment: I have a question what you said is   how the input timeout ANR works, why I need ANR-WatchDog ?

Comment: This will provide you with the full logs which Google don't provide sometime. If you see the question, the stack trace is empty.